# Arc diff hangs on git commit

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I'm trying to get a good workflow working for Phabricator and recently made a few changes to our test project to work out some things. I made several changes but forgot to put them in their own feature branches. All of the changes were uncommitted to git. I went ahead a created feature branches as applicable for the changes I made and committed them. I thought I'd be able to switch to each branch and do an `arc diff` to create the code reviews for them (and I still think I can do this). However, when I execute `arc diff` on the currently-checked-out branch, the command never completes. To see what was going on, I ran `arc diff --trace`. The output is below. As you can surmise, it gets through the commit message specification (in my case via Notepad++) and then just completely dies on the `[26] git diff` line (and by "dies" I mean it hangs and never completes).

```
libphutil loaded from 'S:\web\_arcanist\libphutil\src'.
arcanist loaded from 'S:\web\_arcanist\arcanist\src'.
Working Copy: Reading .arcconfig from "S:\web\_apollo\andreas\bonfire3/.arcconfi
g".
Working Copy: Path "S:\web\_apollo\andreas\bonfire3" is part of `git` working co
py "S:\web\_apollo\andreas\bonfire3".
Working Copy: Project root is at "S:\web\_apollo\andreas\bonfire3".
>>> [0] <conduit> conduit.connect() <bytes = 445>
>>> [1] <http> http://phabricator.mydomain.com/api/conduit.connect
<<< [1] <http> 1,086,426 us
<<< [0] <conduit> 1,089,191 us
>>> [2] <exec> $ git diff --no-ext-diff --no-textconv --raw "HEAD" --
>>> [3] <exec> $ git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
>>> [4] <exec> $ git diff-files --name-only
<<< [3] <exec> 56,380 us
<<< [2] <exec> 84,804 us
<<< [4] <exec> 60,751 us
>>> [5] <event> diff.didCollectChanges <listeners = 0>
<<< [5] <event> 744 us
>>> [6] <exec> $ git rev-parse --verify HEAD^
<<< [6] <exec> 44,265 us
>>> [7] <exec> $ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name '@{upstream}'
<<< [7] <exec> 75,134 us
>>> [8] <exec> $ git rev-parse --git-dir
<<< [8] <exec> 63,179 us
>>> [9] <exec> $ git cat-file -t "origin/master"
<<< [9] <exec> 35,771 us
>>> [10] <exec> $ git merge-base "origin/master" HEAD
<<< [10] <exec> 70,249 us
>>> [11] <exec> $ git log --first-parent --format=medium "91098728f2d669d8c1ce96
c2ba84059b57241fb6"..HEAD
<<< [11] <exec> 59,466 us
>>> [12] <exec> $ git log "HEAD" --not "91098728f2d669d8c1ce96c2ba84059b57241fb6
" --format=%H%x01%T%x01%P%x01%at%x01%an%x01%aE%x01%s%x01%s%n%n%b%x02 --
<<< [12] <exec> 57,813 us
>>> [13] <conduit> differential.query() <bytes = 415>
>>> [14] <http> http://phabricator.mydomain.com/api/differential.query
<<< [14] <http> 136,410 us
<<< [13] <conduit> 139,261 us
You have a saved revision message in '.git\arc\create-message'.
Message begins:

       Installed DBV

You can use this message, or discard it.

    Do you want to use this message? [Y/n] y

>>> [15] <exec> $ git log "HEAD" --not "91098728f2d669d8c1ce96c2ba84059b57241fb6
" --format=%H%x01%T%x01%P%x01%at%x01%an%x01%aE%x01%s%x01%s%n%n%b%x02 --
<<< [15] <exec> 40,860 us
>>> [16] <conduit> differential.parsecommitmessage() <bytes = 356>
>>> [17] <http> http://phabricator.mydomain.com/api/differential.parsecommitmessa
ge
<<< [17] <http> 154,222 us
<<< [16] <conduit> 155,662 us
>>> [18] <event> diff.willBuildMessage <listeners = 0>
<<< [18] <event> 556 us
>>> [19] <exec> $ git branch --no-color
<<< [19] <exec> 60,581 us
>>> [20] <exec> $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -n
osession  "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Temp\2\edit.6y1tzwocr1ookc0c\new-commi
t"
<<< [20] <exec> 2,583,272 us
>>> [21] <conduit> differential.parsecommitmessage() <bytes = 434>
>>> [22] <http> http://phabricator.mydomain.com/api/differential.parsecommitmessa
ge
<<< [22] <http> 156,039 us
<<< [21] <conduit> 158,955 us
>>> [23] <conduit> user.query() <bytes = 254>
>>> [24] <http> http://phabricator.mydomain.com/api/user.query
<<< [24] <http> 101,262 us
<<< [23] <conduit> 103,793 us
>>> [25] <event> diff.didBuildMessage <listeners = 0>
<<< [25] <event> 1,169 us
Linting...
No lint engine configured for this project.
Running unit tests...
No unit test engine is configured for this project.
>>> [26] <exec> $ git diff --no-ext-diff --no-textconv --no-color --src-prefix=a
/ --dst-prefix=b/ -U32767 -M -C "91098728f2d669d8c1ce96c2ba84059b57241fb6" --
```

I've tried copying the `git diff` command into a separate terminal and it works fine. I assumed maybe something was wrong with PHP's `exec` command locally, so I created a quick 2 line PHP file to run the `git diff` command through that...worked fine. I've left the `arc diff` command running at that line for several hours and it just doesn't complete. Any ideas as to how to troubleshoot this?

**UPDATE**
I forgot to mention that `arc diff` also hangs on a `git commit --amend`, too.

Comment: I have a similar Problem with git haning on `git commit --ammend`. Did you solve your Problem? Can you provide some sort of Solution in an Edit or your own Answer?

Comment: I think I never found a solution to this. I just updated arcanist and it started working again. The #phabricator irc room on freenode is a great place to ask for help, though, if updating arc doesn't work.

Comment: For me it seemed it was a problem with to large commits. I manually added the files using `git add .` and `git push` and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I made debugging and discovered that the reason was a warning message "LF will be replaced by CRLF.." during "git diff" execution.
I made "git config core.safecrlf false" and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While @summerwind's answer works. It might be safer to delete the files causing the `LF will be replaced by CRLF`, and then check them back out.

```
:: del /s/q/f will deiete the .git folder, so you must specify the folder explicity
del /s/q/f <some-folder>
git checkout <some-folder>
```

or

```
# actually it is just good practice
rm -rfv <some-folder>
git checkout <some-folder>
```